# Unable to translate Postman request in Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to connect to a site via python request.
The request works perfectly in postman, but when I translate the request into Python requests code via postman, it doesn't work

```http
  POST /signin?_ga=2.124528870.158973783.162362132-6632635.1623321632 HTTP/1.1
Host: abc.vivaling.com
Host: abc.vivaling.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://abc.vivaling.com
Referer: https://abc.vivaling.com/signin?_ga=2.124528870.158973783.162362132-6632635.1623321632
Content-Length: 112
Cookie: SSZZEZE96f528d192648420d997derif2bfa4=QAaSIfTLRdGQBbxzerWjHulytU0jWDFgI7UvS7PaMg89k; _dc_gtm_UA-4935454-1=1; _ga=GA1.3.1561222616.1618850693; _gid=GA1.3.1183631645.1623592158; has_js=1

submitted%5Bemail%5D=mymail%40domain.com&submitted%5Bpassword%5D=My%3FPassword&form_id=webform_client_form_5
```

Python request:

```python
import requests

url = "https://abc.vivaling.com/signin?_ga=2.124528870.158973783.162362132-6632635.1623321632"

payload = "submitted%5Bemail%5D=mymail%40domain.com&submitted%5Bpassword%5D=My%3FPassword&form_id=webform_client_form_5"
headers = {
  'Host': 'abc.vivaling.com',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Origin': 'https://abc.vivaling.com',
  'Referer': 'https://abc.vivaling.com/signin?_ga=2.124528870.158973783.162362132-6632635.1623321632',
  'Content-Length': '112',
  'Cookie': '_dc_gtm_UA-49392042-1=1; _ga=GA1.2.1577422616.1618850693; _gat_UA-49392042-1=1; _gid=GA1.2.516258050.1623592167; SSZZEZE96f528d192648420d997derif2bfa4=QAaSIfTLRdGQBbxzerWjHulytU0jWDFgI7UvS7PaMg89k; _dc_gtm_UA-4935454-1=1; _ga=GA1.3.1561222616.1618850693; _gid=GA1.3.1183631645.1623592158; has_js=1'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I have a code 200, but I don't have the right page, as if the authentication had failed...
There is probably some extra code that I need to clean up, but I don't see why it doesn't work.
How can I debug this?

Thanks,

Comment: I usually debug issues like this using a request bin - https://requestbin.net/ Make a bin, change the url you're sending your request to and you can compare what the two different request methods look like. You might need to change the `Host:` header you're sending too fyi

Comment: I use the similar method as @Macattack but with https://httpbin.org and I use https://httpbin.org/post for `POST` request

Comment: often it is good to set `User-Agent` from real web browser. Other problem can makes Cookies so it is good to use `Session()` and first use GET request without coockies to get fresh cookies. And if you get wrong page then you should check what you get. Maybe there is information what makes problem - or information that code was recognized as bot/script and it ask for ReCaptcha.

Comment: other method is to use local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (or [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)) and send both requests by proxy to see differences.

Comment: @Macattack, Thanks guys, thanks to your advice I was able to solve my problem.
Using the session mode seems to have solved the problem. And I discovered requestbin.net and Charles (I trying to make it work with vscode)
Thanks again